# Set two primary keys but reset the second primary key for each first primary key value - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2017-express

I am trying to make a comment section for products. I am setting two primary keys, the `CommentID` and the `ProductID` for the `Comments` table. But what I want to do with the primary keys is as follows: for each `ProductID`, the `CommentID` should start counting from the beginning. So for `ProductID = 1`, the `CommentID` should start from 1 and be incremented, for `ProductID = 2`, the `CommentID` should also start from 1 and be incremented, and so on. Same time the `ProductID` is the foreign key that points on Product table.

Can someone guide me how to archive that, is it a good practice or does a better workaround exist except making two primary keys?

Thank you!

Comment: You should learn what terminology means before you (mis)use it.   A table can only have one Primary Key.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key

Answer (score 2):

I would use `IDENTITY` column/sequence(single PK):

```
CREATE TABLE comments(comment_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,  
                      product_id INT REFERENCES Product(product_id),
                      some_text VARCHAR(1000),
                      -- ...
                      );
```

And selecting:

```
SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY comment_id) AS rn 
  -- if you really need consecutive numbers
FROM comments
WHERE product_id = ?
```

Comment: a dumb question. how do I make an insert in this case? I mean, do I have to specify the PRoductID each time I make an insert!

Comment: And what does references do? how is it different from foreign key?

Comment: @Tinaira Yesm you have to specify ProductId. `REFERENCES` is inline version of foreign key.

Comment: OK. But as much as I see the CommentID will increment independently from the ProductID. So it will not start over when I chose a different Product to Comment

Comment: @Tinaira No, it won't. That is why I posted query with ROW_NUMBER. I guess you want it for showing in application. It is not DB concern at all.

Comment: ok. but the db should do as follow: for the selected productid to start the commentid from 1. So if I select product with id 1 and start making comments it should increment the commentid according to the product id. if I select productid=2 and start commenting it should reset the commentid for that particular product. so the commentid should be depending on the productid

Comment: @Tinaira No, it won't work that way. And I don't see a point of doing so. If you still insist you could calculate it on the fly with: `SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY productId ORDER BY comment_id) AS rn 
FROM comments`. Please note that comments may be deleted as well. Then you don't get consecutive numbers.

Comment: either there is a way that sql server does it autmatically or I have to first get the max commentid of the selected product, add 1 to it and set it as the commentid

Comment: @Tinaira  `have to first get the max commentid of the selected product, add 1 to it and set it as the commentid`. I strongly recommend not doing so. It may fail with multiple concurrent transactions.

Comment: ok. but so, I must check if the commentid and productid already exist, like commentid=1 and productid=2 that it shouldn't get repeated. I want that both together work as one primary key

Comment: I understand your code now. The column you add in the select statement is just the highest commentid number regarding to the productid. It was at first a bit confusing because I expected something else, but now it makes sense